# Pyspark Ranking based on previous/current row

Tags: pyspark

Below is my source and expected output dataframe

[image: Input/Expected dataframe]

I need to apply the below logic and calculate the final rank value
if previous row(hdr) == current row(hdr) & previous row(dtl) == current row (dtl),
then assign previous row rank else previous row rank + 1

I couldn't move forward post dense ranking. Can you please share your inputs? I am trying to avoid Window without partitionBy column considering potential performance overhead

```
sample = [(100,1000),(100, 1000), (100, 2000), (200, 1000), (200,1000), (300,1000), (300,2000)]
test = spark.createDataFrame(sample,['hdr','dtl'])
spec = Window.partitionBy('hdr').orderBy('hdr','dtl')
test.withColumn('dense', func.dense_rank().over(spec)).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think ranking without windowing is possible and in your case since ranking needs to happen on entire dataset its not possible to avoid window function without partitionBy, But we can reduce huge amount of data going into one partition with below code.

```
sample = [(100,1000),(100, 1000), (100, 2000), (200, 1000), (200,1000), (300,1000), (300,2000)]
test = spark.createDataFrame(sample,['hdr','dtl'])

# Since we select only distinct of hdr and dtl huge amount of data is eliminated.
dist_hdr_dtl=test.select("hdr","dtl").distinct()

# Since data size is reduced we can use this window spec.
spec = Window.orderBy('hdr','dtl')
dist_hdr_dtl=dist_hdr_dtl.withColumn('final_rank', dense_rank().over(spec))

# join it with original data to get the ranks.
Note: if distinct dataset is not very huge you can use broadcast join which will improve performance
test.join(dist_hdr_dtl,["hdr","dtl"],"inner").orderBy('hdr','dtl').show()

+---+----+----------+
|hdr| dtl|final_rank|
+---+----+----------+
|100|1000|         1|
|100|1000|         1|
|100|2000|         2|
|200|1000|         3|
|200|1000|         3|
|300|1000|         4|
|300|2000|         5|
+---+----+----------+
```

Comment: thanks girish.since i had a very huge data set with billion rows, wondering if i have a choice and avoid moving dataset to one partition.

Comment: I think that's unavoidable....but as I mentioned you can reduce the amount of data that is being moved....